# How to two way bind multiple strings to multiple textboxes in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have an application that receives from the user a list of string.

The application needs to display that list and provide a `TextBox` per each string (for additional user input).
Eventually the application will gather the values from the `TextBox` elements, one value per user input-string.

The layout of the application is a Grid based layout. Here is a mockup example developed in Python tkinter:

[image]

I am trying to build the same thing in WPF and can't find the way to correctly bind the items.
I tried multiple approaches, none results in a working window.
Here is my latest version:

**XAML**

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="86"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Opcode" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="Courier New" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label Content="Operand" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="Courier New" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="Opcodes" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Height="22" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsTextSearchEnabled="False" SelectionChanged="Opcodes_SelectionChanged"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="Operand" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="20" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsUndoEnabled="False" IsEnabled="False"/>
        <Label Content="&gt;" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="11" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="PinGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Margin="0,0,0,4" IsTabStop="False">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="2" Width="14" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Medium" FontFamily="Courier New" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl x:Name="PinDataGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" IsTabStop="False">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>

        <WrapPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button x:Name="Cancel" Content="_Cancel" IsCancel="True" Width="50" Click="Cancel_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="Ok" Content="_Ok" Margin="10,0,0,0" IsDefault="True" Width="50" Click="Ok_Click"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private ObservableCollection<string> Pins { get; set; } = null;
private List<string> PinsData { get; set; } = null;        
private string OperandData { get; set; } = null;
```

(window c-tor)

```
Pins = new ObservableCollection<string>(<user provided list of pins>);
PinGrid.ItemsSource = Pins;

PinsData = new List<string>();
for(int i = 0; i < Pins.Count; i++)
{
    PinsData.Add("X");
    TextBox t = new TextBox()
    {
        Margin = new Thickness(2, 0, 2, 0),
        Padding = new Thickness(0),
        Width = 14,
        FontSize = 13,
        FontWeight = FontWeights.Medium,
        FontFamily = new FontFamily("Courier New"),
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
        HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
        VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
    };

    Binding b = new Binding();
    b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    b.Path = new PropertyPath("PinsData[" + i + "]");
    t.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, b);
    PinDataGrid.Items.Add(t);
}

Opcodes.Items.Add(String.Empty); // add empty entry for clear operation
foreach (string opcode in <user provided list of opcodes>)
    Opcodes.Items.Add(opcode);

DataContext = this;
```

Here is the WPF version:
[image]

As you can see, the `X` is not showing in the `TextBox` and the binding didn't happen. What am I doing wrong? How can I create the two way binding of text boxes to the `PinsData` list of strings?

It might be that my whole approach is wrong - so such kinds of inputs will be more than welcomed.

Comment: I can really get what you are trying to achieve, could you be more specific ? In every textbox below those columns you have to show what ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez: check the Python mockup. the string are user input. I need to create a textbox per each string, initialize it with 'X' and bind it to a list<strings> so i can later get the user TextBox values

Comment: let's see if I got it :P for every item in your `Pins` you create a column. When the application starts it must show a `X` and bind the items in your `Pins` without showing them ? I'm sorry but many times what we think its easy to understand its harder for those who aren't in the project

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez: for every item in `Pins`, i create a `TextBox` which is binded to a string inside the `PinsData` list. The `PinsData` list elements are initialized to`X`

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to tell you why it didn't work for you first.

In C# `strings` are immutable so, as you were binding using a two-way mode, every time you changed the string it was a different object instance. Try changing your `b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay`to `OneWay` and you will see the "X" there, but it won't work for what you want.

Managed to get the link I used once when I faced a similar issue
[binding string](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saguar/2017/03/03/the-story-of-a-in-bindable-string/)

---

To achieve what you want you should do the following:

- Create a new class to control your item changes like this:

  ```
  public class PinsDataItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
       private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
         {
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
         }

       string text;

       public PinsDataItem(string value)
         {
          this.Text = value;
         }

  public string Text
  {
      get
      {
          return text;
      }
      set
      {
          if (text != value)
          {
              text = value;
          }
          NotifyPropertyChanged("Value");
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- Your `for`should change to this:

  ```
   PinsData = new List<PinsDataItem>();

      for (int i = 0; i < Pins.Count; i++)
      {
          PinsData.Add(new PinsDataItem("X"));
          TextBox t = new TextBox()
          {
              Margin = new Thickness(2, 0, 2, 0),
              Padding = new Thickness(0),
              Width = 14,
              FontSize = 13,
              FontWeight = FontWeights.Medium,
              FontFamily = new FontFamily("Courier New"),
              HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
              VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
              HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
              VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
          };
          Binding b = new Binding();
          b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
          b.Source = PinsData[i];
          b.Path = new PropertyPath("Text");
          t.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, b);
          PinDataGrid.Items.Add(t);
      }
  ```

This should work for you. Let me know if it didn't :D